# What major translations of the Bible are in the Public Domain?

Tags: bible-translation, copyright

Quoting Biblical text is technically a dicey proposition.  While the original manuscripts are obviously public domain, not every translation is.

Indeed, the NIV even posts the following [copyright notice](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/New-International-Version-NIV-Bible/) on BibleGateway:

> Copyright Information
>
> The NIV text may be quoted in any form (written, visual, electronic or audio), up to and inclusive of five hundred (500) verses without express written permission of the publisher, providing the verses do not amount to a complete book of the Bible nor do the verses quoted account for twenty-five percent (25%) or more of the total text of the work in which they are quoted.
>
> When the NIV is quoted in works that exercise the above fair use clause, notice of copyright must appear on the title or copyright page or opening screen of the work (whichever is appropriate) as follows:
>
> THE HOLY BIBLE, NEW INTERNATIONAL VERSION®, NIV® Copyright © 1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by Biblica, Inc.™ Used by permission. All rights reserved worldwide.
>
> These Scriptures are copyrighted by the Biblica, Inc.™ and have been made available on the Internet for your personal use only. Any other use including, but not limited to, copying or reposting on the Internet is prohibited. These Scriptures may not be altered or modified in any form and must remain in their original context. These Scriptures may not be sold or otherwise offered for sale.

Given this, what significant translations of the Bible can I actually quote at length?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll need to quite the entire Bible in any scholarly setting. And quoting *any* copyrighted work for the purpose of commentary or scholarly discourse is perfectly acceptable. So, for any purpose on this site, I think any translation is acceptable to quote.

Comment: And before anyone says, "This would be better on Politics.SE," a certain moderator [I'm very close](http://politics.stackexchange.com/users/23/affable-geek) to there says, "I want it on C.SE!"

Comment: Stop using your connections to get what you want!!!

Comment: :).............

Comment: Is anything soooo "public domain" or "copylefted" that a scholarly citation doesn't have to have an elaborate footnote, giving publisher's city, etc.?

Comment: Depends on the citation method; it's not really a C.SE discussion, but basically any citation requires a good deal of information just so that anyone doing fact-checking/verification can actually find the same thing. So in short, not for scholarly citation, but for less scholarly citation it's possible to find larger translations that you can just use without additional explanation (NIV or NASB, for instance).

Comment: Are you specifically interested in English-language translations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a [shopping question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4086/20).

Comment: @Flimzy I'm content with allowing this one. Once in public domain it will remain in public domain. Though the list may be incomplete forever, it will never been inaccurate because copyright was suddenly reinstated.

Comment: @fredsbend: Public domain has no bearing on whether a question is a "shopping question." "Which city should I visit?" is a shopping question, even though it has nothing to do with (specifically) buying anything.

Comment: @Flimzy The primary issue with shopping questions in that linked post is "Those involve opinions, not definitive answers." That is not the case with this one.

Comment: @fredsbend: They also contain open-ended lists of answers. That is the case with this one.

Comment: @Flimzy Right, which I conceded in my first comment and gave the reason why I'm content with allowing this one to stay open. We can convert it to community wiki if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### The issue with copyright translations.

One translation that was produced with the specific intention of avoiding copyright entanglements is the [World English Bible](http://ebible.org/web/FRT01.htm#V3).  It is modernization of the American Standard Version (ASV) placed into the public domain.  A paragraph from the site's [FAQ](http://ebible.org/web/webfaq.htm#WhyNoCopyright) is worth quoting:

> The copyright laws of most nations and the international treaties that support them are a mixed blessing. By granting authors and translators a legal monopoly (for a limited, but very long, time) on the right of copying and “first sale” of their works, the law makers have made writing and translating very profitable for some people whose works are in great demand. This has, no doubt, been a factor in the creation of many of the good Modern English translations of the Holy Bible that we now enjoy. The problem with this system, with respect to the Holy Bible, is that it has had the effect of limiting distribution of God’s Word in modern languages. For example, I cannot legally post copies of the entire New International Version of the Holy Bible on my web site in a downloadable, searchable, and readily copyable format without the permission of the International Bible Society and Zondervan (copyright owner and publisher). Zondervan won’t grant such permission unless they get a significant royalty (they quoted me $10,000 + $10/copy distributed) and unless I convince them that my Bible search software is “good enough” for them. Needless to say, the Bible search software that I am writing with the intention of distributing as donorware will not come with the NIV.

Further, organizations such as [The Gideons International](http://www.gideons.org/) that distribute Bibles must pay copyright holders a fee if they wish to give away a modern translation (such as the New King James Version) rather than the King James with all of it's Elizabethanisms.  The restrictions can also have an impact on smaller scales.  The [NASB licence](http://www.lockman.org/tlf/copyright.php#nasb) reads (emphasis in the original):

> The text of the ***New American Standard Bible®*** may be quoted and/or reprinted up to and inclusive of **one thousand (1,000) verses** *without express written permission of The Lockman Foundation,* providing the verses do not amount to **a complete book of the Bible** nor do the verses quoted account for **more than 50%** of the total work in which they are quoted.

These restrictions mean it's ([probably](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/68)) fine to quote a passage or two in an answer on Stack Exchange or in an article or book.  But it's not possible to reprint an entire book of the Bible for the purposes of a ["Manuscript Study"](http://www.intervarsity.org/bible-studies) (AKA, "Communal Discovery Bible Study Method").  While I doubt the Lockman Foundation will have agents tracking down people who print out Mark for their devotional group to mark up, such a practice violates the intentions of the publisher who fronted the money and commissioned the translation.  As Paul says:

> The elders who rule well are to be considered worthy of double honor, especially those who work hard at preaching and teaching. For the Scripture says, “YOU SHALL NOT MUZZLE THE OX WHILE HE IS THRESHING,” and “The laborer is worthy of his wages.”—1<sup>st</sup> Timothy 5:17-18 ([NASB](http://biblehub.com/nasb/1_timothy/5.htm))

Finally, many translations restrict derivative works (such as the WEB effort and my idea of making a [Southern American Version™](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1097/68)).  The US laws concerning [derivative works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) is complicated, but creators who don't want to deal with lawyers would be advised to base their work on translations free of copyright restrictions.

### But God's Word should be free, man!

The Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek texts of the Bible *are* public domain (and a cornerstone of our cultural heritage).  But it turns out that even the [critical text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novum_Testamentum_Graece) is [protected](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openscriptures/9XcB_4Ua6QU/yMgWi6tx43AJ) by copyright laws.  For the general public, this is no great loss as there are plenty of unrestricted options and the licences for most translations allow for the most common uses of the texts.  But all of this has serious implications for scholars who honor the wishes of the Bible publishers.  It's tempting to get angry with the publishers or to ignore the restrictions.

However, we have a duty to comply with the licences of our translations so that the hard-working folks who produce them can afford to keep laboring.  Most of them are reasonable people who are as interested in seeing God's Word preached as you are.  In fact I'll let the Crossway (publishers of the ESV) blog have the [final word](https://web.archive.org/web/20110706132925/http://www.crossway.org/blog/2005/11/how-to-cite-esv/):

> We're not going to come after you if you don't cite quotes from the ESV according to these guidelines. But we'd appreciate it if you did. Using the letters “ESV” also helps us track the popularity of the ESV in the blogosphere.

Comment: I'm going to add WEB to my list (I'm assuming you'll be okay with that), but I like how your post really gets to the heart of the issues, ergo the check mark!

Comment: @Affable Geek: No problem.  This post started as an edit, but it got too big to fit in a bullet point. ;-)

Comment: QUESTION: "What major translations of the Bible are in the Public Domain?"  ANSWER:  In the USA there are only two popular versions [1>[AV] Authorized Version (aka KJV) ;  [2>[ASV] American Standard Version (aka "Revised", "American Standard Revised". NOT to be confused with RSV, which is "Owned").  --- notice, PUBLIC DOMAIN legally means that no one OWNS the works.  All other versions are owned, and ALLOW at the owners choice, varying degrees of  copying (their Policy, not your Right).   With P.D. that means you can copy the work, and publish it yourself, and even copyright your own Version.

Comment: [above] I posted here because I just joined and don't yet have enough "REPUTATION" to answer.  "Public Domain" is often misapplied to books that publishing companies OWN, but who's POLICY is to allow free copying.  They can change their policy to whatever they like, whenever they like.  Then everyone is obliged to follow the new policy.  So hypothetically, if you copy x chapters of WFCV Bible  (whatever free copy version) and send it to a Billion folks, but they decide later they have disagreements with you, they can just change their policy.  --Censorship is managed that way in Democracies.--

Comment: Appreciate it! I made a Bible search application https://aaronjs.pythonanywhere.com and Biblica did not permit using the NIV database (basically they did not share it saying that I am an individual!)
I've got a couple of public domain versions in there. I think I'd add ESV now! :-D

Answer (score 38):

In the United States, Copyright law has two basic categories - protected works and public domain.  When a work has been around long enough (currently 95 years after the first publication or 70 years after the author's death) it enters the public domain, and is therefore allowed to be reproduced at will.

According to the "Copyright Act", any work published prior to 1923 is in the public domain.  This means many older translations are fair use:

- King James Version
- Duoay-Rheims
- Young's Literal
- Darby
- JPS Bible (but *not* the New JPS nor the Jerusalem Bible)

Additionally, some translations were specifically geared to avoid this issue.

- The World English Bible (WEB)
- The [New English Translation](http://bible.org/article/net-bible-copyright) - i.e the ["Net" Bible](http://net.bible.org/) Note: Does not apply if you charge for it, though...
- The WikiSource Translation :)
- The [Lexham translation](http://lexhamenglishbible.com/license/) - Requires attribution and can only be sold if it is less than 25% of a work (or 50% for non-profits)
- The English Standard Version ESV *is* copyrighted, but the terms are intentionally loose:

  > When quotations from the ESV text are used in non-saleable media, such as church bulletins, orders of service, posters, transparencies, or similar media, a complete copyright notice is not required, but the initials (ESV) must appear at the end of the quotation. Publication of any commentary or other Bible reference work produced for commercial sale that uses the English Standard Version must include written permission for use of the ESV text.

Finally, many translations follow the standard of 500 verses, not to exceed 20% of the printed work. This list includes the following translations:

- [NRSV](http://www.nrsv.net/contact/licensing-permissions/)
- [HCSB](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Holman-Christian-Standard-Bible-HCSB/#copy) (250 verses)
- [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/New-International-Version-NIV-Bible/#copy) (as shown above)
- [New Living Translation](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/New-Living-Translation-NLT-Bible/)
- [NKJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/New-King-James-Version-NKJV-Bible/) (Also 250 verses)

Comment: See also [this Meta comment](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/would-quick-link-support-for-biblegateway-be-useful#comment3943_1756) about KJV and the associated discussion.

Comment: You'll find a list of English text Bibles with their date of publication on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_Bible_translations As per the answer above, you'll want to choose the ones that were published 75 years ago or more from this year.

Comment: What is an "autor"? :-) (I guess your browser does not have spell checking enabled.) NIV should be listed separately because it is 25% and "as shown above" might be better as "as detailed in the question". (I would edit it, but I am not certain how NIV should be handled--separate or use "limited number of verses (typically 500) composing no more than a modest percentage (typically 20%) of the writing" with "(VERSE_COUNT, PERCENTAGE)" for each translation. Thanks for correcting the copyright information. (But I am still going to be left with a comment attached! :-( )

Comment: You've made a slight error in your list of translations of the Bible that are in the public domain. You rightly state that the NRSV is still subject copyright, but your mistake lies in the statement that the RSV is in the public domain. The copyright on the New Testament of the RSV dates from 1946; the Old Testament from 1952. Both copyrights are still in force.

Comment: Interesting. Is it sufficient to quote the ESV in a blog post, or link to it at BibleGateway, then declare in the references at the bottom of the post "All Bible quotations are from the ESV unless otherwise stated"?

Comment: RSV is not pre-1923. You're either thinking of the ASV (1901) or the RV (1881,1885).

Comment: To backup @davidbrainerd's comment, please see https://nrsvbibles.org/index.php/licensing/

Comment: The CSB (Christian Standard Bible) allows 1000 verses.  https://csbible.com/about-the-csb/faqs/#faq/may-i-use-the-christian-standard-bible-in-my-writing

Answer (score 21):

I have compiled a database of known public domain Bible translations. My compilation includes the following:

**Versions available:**

- American Standard-ASV1901 (ASV)
- Bible in Basic English (BBE)
- Darby English Bible (DARBY)
- King James Version (KJV)
- Webster's Bible (WBT)
- World English Bible (WEB)
- Young's Literal Translation (YLT)

---

**This database is available on [Github](https://github.com/scrollmapper/bible_databases).**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Christianity SE. I have suggested an edit that doesn't look so spammy - when you get a chance check out our [about] page and what makes us [different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/4188) than other sites - I hope you'll stick around and provide some valuable contributions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the welcome! I will have a look around.

Comment: Note that the KJV is under Crown Copyright in the UK, although it is PD in the US.

Answer (score 16):

Of the non-public domain translations, the NET Bible has the most liberal licence for copying passages - you can read its [licence](http://bible.org/article/net-bible-copyright). You can copy, but not alter or distribute commercially.

If you wish to have complete freedom to act without legal restriction then you need a public domain translation. There are a number of translations which are out of copyright due to age. These are in the public domain, but their language tends to be archaic and their scholarship dates from before our modern knowledge of manuscripts etc. Other people have mentioned the World English Bible, which is a revision of the old ASV and has been released into the public domain. Think of it as similar to the ESV in style though based on the majority Byzantine texts in the NT.

Another option, though it only covers the NT and part of the OT at this time, is the [Open English Bible](http://openenglishbible.org) (which as a disclaimer I'm involved in). This is attempting to create a modern English translation which is completely free of copyright restriction, so that you can use it however you feel appropriate.

Comment: Hi Russell and welcome to _[Christianity.SE]_.  Thank you for bringing the OEB to my attention; this is the first I've heard of the project.  It sounds like you might be just the sort of expert we are looking to attract and I hope you will find the time to answer (and perhaps ask) some more questions.  I'd also like to direct your attention to _[Hermeneutics.SE]_, which is our sister site where [translation questions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1784/914) sometimes get migrated.  In any case, thank you for the contribution and I look forward to exploring the OEB project!

Answer (score 9):

You should also look at the Open English Bible here:

[Welcome to the Open English Bible.](http://openenglishbible.org/)

The Open English Bible project aims to create the first modern English translation of the Bible which is completely free of copyright restrictions and available without cost for any purpose.

The OEB has no restrictions on what its readers and users can do with it (for both good and bad). You may quote it, publish it in part or full, on their blogs, in your churches, remix it, reword it, correct its egregious translation mistakes or indeed add your own.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).  This is a good answer!

Answer (score 9):

Cambridge University holds the copyright to the King James version (through a centuries-long series of transfers of ownership rights), but only in the United Kingdom. I think the King James version can be freely quoted in books published in the U.S. and other countries. Source: [The Queen's Printer's Patent.](http://www.cambridge.org/about-us/who-we-are/queens-printers-patent)

Also see Wikipedia for a long article on why Cambridge holds the King James copyright.
[King James Version (Wikipedia).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version)

Comment: Welcome to the site! What follows next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer (which is good); it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first). As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). I hope to see you around!

Comment: This is a trivial point, but in fact, Cambridge University Press does not hold the _copyright_ to the KJV—The copyright is held by the Crown. Cambridge University Press is the current possessor of the Royal _letters patent_ that permit them to print, publish and distribute the KJV in the UK, although another firm, Collins, holds parallel rights in Scotland.

Comment: I was just looking through & thought I add this reference:
https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/FAQ.php
Q: Can I quote the King James Bible?
A: Yes, if you live in the United States or most countries outside of the United Kingdom, you may freely quote the King James Bible (KJV). If you live within the United Kingdom and are wanting to quote the KJV, you may likely do so with no fee if your quote meets certain requirements. Rights to the King James Bible in the United Kingdom are vested in the Crown and administered by Cambridge University Press, the Crown's patentee.

Answer (score 8):

The Following is a list of Public Domain bibles I tend to use.

- Septuagint in American English 2012
- World English Bible
- Twentieth Century New Testament
- Open English Bible [an update of the 20cNT]
- The Updated King James Version
- The American Standard Version
- The Work of God's Children Illustrated Bible (based on Challoner Revision of the Douay–Rheims Bible)
- The Bible in Basic English
- Noah Webster's Revision.

Answer (score 1):

The 2009AD Catholic Public Domain Version ([CPDV](http://sacredbible.org/)) is a translation of the 382AD Latin Vulgate (LV) by Saint Jerome, using the public domain 1899AD Douay-Rheims Catholic Bible ([DRA](https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Douay-Rheims-1899-American-Edition-DRA-Bible/)) as a guide. See DRA and LV [history](http://www.drbo.org/about.htm).