# How do i get the original text of the bible?

Tags: bible

I need this help. I am developing a bible API for my website and i want to know where to find the original text in html format. Do I need to write to the publishers or on which website can I get 100% of the original bible text, both old and new testaments. I do not want to use others API and i would be glad to get it in many other versions. 
THANK YOU FOR ANY GOOD ANSWERS...

Comment: There's no such original manuscripts in existence of ANY holy book (well, not of Christianity, Judaism, or Islam). For starters, I would recommend that you research the history of the Holy Bible. :)

Comment: Thanks, but i just want the text of the bible for a bible app. Just like the one on http://www.bibla.org

Comment: I would say this is probably off topic for this site since it's not really a question about what a particular church believes. So I'm not going to make this an answer but I want you to have one none the less. This link will help you http://lmgtfy.com/?q=download+bible+in+html .

Comment: Thank you very much. I an glad you told me this id off topic. I am new to this community and i would try not to repeat any such question. Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a general resource request.

Comment: This question appears to be more about the Bible than about Christianity. In any case, it is not possible to obtain the original manuscripts of the Bible, because most of them are destroyed, and earliest manuscripts we have left are copies.

Comment: Start [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16377/what-major-translations-of-the-bible-are-in-the-public-domain-and-therefore-not) to see which versions are public domain, then try searching for full text of those versions.

Comment: Check out biblia.com

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense; and it makese even less sense with your comments. The original text of the Bible is not in English.  The English translations all have copyrights (although some, such as KJV, have expired).  You clearly need to do some research first. You don't even have the most basic understanding of what the Bible is, to ask a meaningful question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the full text of a particular translation in your own Bible API then you need to contact the publisher of that translation or, you can use a translation that is in the [public domain](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16377/what-major-translations-of-the-bible-are-in-the-public-domain-and-therefore-not).